# How can I see my created tables structure in Sqlite with out using any commands

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How can I see the structure of Table in sqlite without using any commands.
http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html - this will help us to find the structure of the table using commands in android.But I hear there is a plugin which help us to get the structure of the table.

Comment: You want to use SQLite.... Without using SQL?

Comment: Do u want to hear the Software name from here?????

Comment: if u r using eclipse u can download this plugin [ http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/ ]

Comment: @Avadhani...Keep respect to everybody.I am just beginner and learning android myself.That is why asked this question.

Comment: @Shiva ..Thank you for help me.Please mention this as answer,this is the answer I searched.

Comment: @Ann- I have written it as an answer also u can mark it as right

Comment: @Ann- haha Confused man what was that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u r using eclipse u can download this plugin just a copy paste of a .jar file :)
Just go through 
this [Link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) follow instructions and see database in emulator of Eclipse.

Normally Database stored in //data/data//databases/ folder of the Android Device.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse Indigo and Up Version then you can do the following.

1. Download eclipse plugin for SQlite from [here](http://www.questoid.com/Download.aspx)
2. Unzip `sqlitexmlbrowser_1.2.0.zip` file and get `net.cellobject.sqlitexmlbrowser_1.2.0.jar` and put that file in your `eclipse\plugins` folder.
3. Restart your eclipse
4. In Eclipse Go to `Windows->Show View->Other` This new installed plugin would be there. (In EclipseJuno it automatically attach that things to the current perspective)
5. How to open your sqlite file using this plugin see this [video](http://www.questoid.com/Tools/CellObjectSQLiteXMLBrowser.aspx)
6. You can see the structure as well as the data using this plugin.